# Send multiple data with $.ajax - fails

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, object, serialization

I have a sortable ordered list and use nestedSortable for it.
And it works.
But now I want to add some data to the ajax request and this fails.

```
var sorted = $('ol.sortable').nestedSortable("serialize");
var dataUrl = {};
  $( "ol.sortable li" ).each(function( index ) {
  //console.log( $( this ).attr("id").replace(/\D/g, '') + ": " + $( this ).attr("data-url") );
  dataUrl[$( this ).attr("id").replace(/\D/g, '')] = $( this ).attr("data-url");
});

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: {sort: sorted, dataurl: dataUrl},
```

Now the problem is when I try to use a PHP foreach-loop it fails for the first data "sort".
This data is now a string.
The second part "dataurl" is an object and I can iterate through it with foreach.

When I can change the order

```
data: {dataurl: dataUrl, sort: sorted}
```

then suddenly my dataurl is a string and the "sort" is an object.

I also tried to set the dataType: JSON but that doesn't change anything.

Have I done something wrong? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way i would do it :

```
var sorted = $('ol.sortable').nestedSortable("serialize");
var dataUrl = {};
$( "ol.sortable li" ).each(function( index ) {
  //console.log( $( this ).attr("id").replace(/\D/g, '') + ": " + $( this ).attr("data-url") );
  dataUrl[$( this ).attr("id").replace(/\D/g, '')] = $( this ).attr("data-url");
});

var sendedData = {};
sendedData.sort = sorted;
sendedData.dataurl = dataUrl;
$.ajax({
    url: 'myFile.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: sendedData,
    success: function(result) {
        // Add your own logic here
    }
});
```